# Enviar información de un formulario en un url

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Te explico algo mas, creo que no lo explique bien del todo.

Tengo que crear un formulario de registro en un web, este formulario tiene que enviar esos datos a una aplicación externa que a su vez me tiene que devolver unos valores y luego procesarlos.

El formulario de de registro debe tener tres campo minimos:

- ID que es siempre la misma, me da la aplicación.
- Usuario.
- Password.

Tenia pensado hacer algo parecido a lo que me dijo Ivan:

```
<form action="http://direccion.com" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Escriba su nombre">
    <input type="number" name="edad" placeholder="Escriba su edad">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos">
</form>
```

y me genera un envio de datos:

http://direccion.com/?nombre=nombre&edad=edad

¿Como puedo incluir la ide fija?

http://direccion.com/?ID=ID&nombre=nombre&edad=nombre

¿Como puedo procesar lo que me devuelva?

Gracias!!!

Comment: deberias de aclarar mas tu pregunta, lo que deseas es un peticion **get** asi de simple, pero no dices en que lo utilizaras, o para que lo quieres especificamente

Comment: he reformulado la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

En el action de tu form pones la url, y luego le pones el metodo por el cual quieres enviar los datos, en éste caso, si quieres que se vean en la url, tu método debe de ser **GET** y el nombre que quieres que tenga debe de ir en los atributos **name** de cada input. Por ejemplo:

Suponiendo que tienes dos archivos, formulario.php que muestra el siguiente formulario, y recibir.php que recibirá tus datos:

```
<form action="recibir.php" method="GET">
   <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Escriba su nombre">
   <input type="number" name="edad" placeholder="Escriba su edad">
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos">
</form>
```

Teniendo esto, ya puedes enviar los datos al archivo **recibir.php**, que tendría algo como lo siguiente:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET['nombre']) //nombre es el name que le pusiste al input de nombre
var_dump($_GET['edad']) //edad es el name que le pusiste al input edad
```